# Contract-first WCF services - still valid?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, wsdl

I am attempting to create a few WCF web services from existing WSDLs.  There are a few awesome questions on SO for this, ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221121/generate-webservice-from-wsdl), definitely more) but many of these are from 3 years ago, and I end up wondering if the advice is still valid.  If it is, how do I finish integrating it into a WCF project in Visual Studio 2010?  The questions and linked blog posts are considerably mum about how one configures a .svc to use the converted WSDL after it's been run through `svchost.exe` (see linked question 1 for details on that), and a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx) linked in the thread suggests there is a way to make Visual Studio create a .svc around a converted WSDL, but I cannot find this anywhere in either the program's interface or the documentation.

So, the question, I suppose, would be: What is the generally recommended way to approach contract-first web service design in Visual Studio 2010/.NET 4.0?

Comment: If you're using **SOAP** services - yes, absolutely! Nothing has changed. If you happen to have to talk to e.g. a third-party which doesn't make their WSDL available online (via `url?wsdl`), then there's really hardly any other way to build your service client ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't changed. You can still generate a service interface and its data contracts using svcutil and a WSDL. Even a client will be generated, though you won't need that.

You can then create a .svc-file, which merely instructs a ServiceHost which class to host, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925941/how-do-i-generate-the-svc-file):

```
<% @ServiceHost Service="MyNamespace.MyServiceImplementationTypeName" %>
```

Your implementation of course has to implement the generated service interface.